# Activity Indicator will not load after UIWebView Has Loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to get the activity indicator to stop animating once the view has loaded. Currently, the view has loaded but the activity indicator does not stop circulating. Here is my code:

```
    UIWebView *elionWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 375, 579)];
    [self.view addSubview:elionWebView];
    elionWebView.delegate = self;

    //Start the Activity Indicator
    [self webViewDidStartLoad:elionWebView]; 

    //Load Website
    NSString* url = @"https://google.com/";
    NSURL* nsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
    [self webViewDidFinishLoad:elionWebView];
    [elionWebView loadRequest:request];
}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    //Start the Activity Indicator
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityView.center = CGPointMake(187.5, 370);
    [activityView startAnimating];
    activityView.tag = 100;
    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self.view viewWithTag:100].hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code. Firstly, `NSURLRequest` does not actually load the URL. There are different ways to do the download. Look at `NSURLConnection` for the simplest way to do a synchronous download.

Secondly, I suggest you declare your `UIActivityIndicatorView` as a member variable of your class rather than tagging the view.

There are `UIActivityIndicatorView` methods for starting and stopping animations. You should use `stopAnimating` to stop the animation. If you have set the property `hidesWhenStopped` to YES on the view, then you will get the behavior you want. If you do not want the indicator after animation has stopped, use `removeFromSuperview` to get rid of it.